# Looking for guidence and direction to turn live data into online graphs

Tags: html, highcharts, server, udp

Im currently looking for a way to turn data from a machine into graphs that update live on a website. Currently I am receiving the data in a UDP format from the machine to my computer at home. I know if I can get the data to a url then I can direct it to my graphs but the part I am struggling with is the posting the data to the url. I do have some limited coding experience but really feel pretty new to this kind of stuff.

this is a sample of the data coming from my machine ……

UDP Site 258 pH: 3.53  ORP: 136  Count No. 70 Time: 4:33:18 PM

and ideas are greatly appreciated 
thanks for your assistance.

Comment: presumably there is already code that you're using to turn these packets into that "sample of the data".  why not just pipe that into a database somewhere then use one of the many frameworks to expose that in some way that makes sense.  depending on data rates you could think about using something like sockets.io to allow the server to "push" data to the UI

Comment: You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. As a Highcharts supporter all I can do is sent you links to the documentation where you can see how the included data should look like. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database and https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart